# How to compile pom.xml without generating project in Maven?

Tags: maven-2

I have pom.xml file that contains dependencies and files to checkout from svn so there is no no need to generate project. I just need these libraries and those files, so is there any way to get them without generating a project with maven directory structure?

Comment: What do you mean by "contains ... files"? These are normally the files from your project. So compiling a pom normally means: 1. instantiate the project from the pom 2. do the normal maven things with it. Build server do just that.

Comment: We want to use Maven just to download libraries and download other files not source code

Comment: That is an unusual usage of Maven. It does not hurt to create a base project (jar), and include there the POM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure from your question what do you want. If you have pom.xml file and you want to download all dependencies defined in it, you can call

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

For more options look [maven copy-dependencies task page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html)

If you are asking how to create pom that will contain no code, but only dependencies, you can do that by specifying `pom` packaging.